# Pod Update of Firebase throwing errors

Tags: firebase, swift3, podfile, firebase-performance

I am trying to install the Firebase Performance SDK and following their instructions on the site:

https://firebase.google.com/docs/perf-mon/get-started-ios

When I run the pod install step it gives me the following error:

firebase performance required by podfile

I run the pod update command and everything runs on the pod install but then when I open up my workspace I get errors in swift as such:

- FIRDatabaseReference has been renamed to DatabaseReference
- FIRDatabase has been renamed to Database
- FIRFirebase.database().reference is now Database.database.reference

which then give the error

- Database has no member reference

What gives!? Has anyone gotten these error after updating their podfile with Firebase!?

Pod file is as such:

```
# Uncomment this line to define a global platform for your project
 platform :ios, '9.0'

target 'Pool' do
    # Uncommnet this line if you're using Swift
    use_frameworks!

    #Pods for firebase pool
    pod 'Firebase', '>=2.5.1' <--- This has been removed from the podfile as suggested 
    pod 'Firebase/Core'
    pod 'Firebase/Performance'
    pod 'Firebase/Auth'
    pod 'Firebase/Database'
    pod 'Firebase/Storage'
    pod 'Firebase/Crash'

    target 'PoolTests' do
     # inherit! :search_paths
    end


    target 'PoolUITests' do
     # inherit! :search_paths
    end

end
```

Result of pod install
[image]

Error in xcode after pod install/update:
[image]

Comment: Show me your Podfile

Comment: @Alwin i updated the init question with the podfile

Comment: is this all pods are used in your app? especially  pod 'Firebase', '>=2.5.1'

Comment: are you trying to use Firebase version  2.5.1. The firebase version Depend upon your platform :ios, '8.0'

Comment: @alwin should i remove the >=2.5.1 1? and what should I put the ios: 8.0 to!? 9.0

Comment: remove pod 'Firebase', '>=2.5.1' and give pod install

Comment: Same result... its frustrating that the update would break it this way!?

Comment: Worst part, why make suggestions for renaming the functions to only lead me to the error that the functions does not have that member....

Comment: can you show me the screenshot in terminal

Comment: @Alwin added screen shot, i also updated my cocoapods

Comment: I think the pods are working fine. Can you show the error code too

Comment: @Alwin xcode error screenshot added as well. As you can see its asking me to remove all the FIR throughout the entire project

Comment: are you import FirebaseDatabase in your VC?

Comment: @Alwin, yes, I have the import Firebase in the VC's, the app worked fine up until i do the pod install/update. Had I never tried to add the Firebase Performance SDK which required the pod update I would not have this issue now!?

Comment: you should import FirebaseDatabase in your VC

Comment: @Alwin are you saying i need both import Firebase and import FirebaseDatabase in my VCs or just import FirebaseDatabase!?

Comment: I did that and I get the same result, it wants to remove the FIR as in the error screen shot!!

Comment: both Firebase and FirebaseDatabase.... Are you import Firebase in AppDelegate and configure?

Comment: Yes i am. As stated this was all working fine before the pod install/update since adding the Firebase performance SDK

Comment: I sry I don't understand what happened. The Firebase/Performance is in beta version

Answer (score 2):

Here's a guide for upgrading Firebase iOS:
https://firebase.google.com/support/guides/firebase-ios

With 4.0 in particular, the Swift interfaces have been cleaned up to make it more "Swifty" which is why you're seeing those rename warning.

After the renaming, accessing the database reference should look like:

let ref:DatabaseReference = Database.database().reference()

For the updated docs of the new swift interface, see here:
https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/ios/firebasedatabase/api/reference/Classes/FIRDatabase

Comment: it throws an error with let ref:DatabaseReference = Database.database().reference().... first one is to remove the () on the database() function and once you do that it throws the Database has no member reference  error!?

Comment: "Database" might be conflicting with another class in your app. You might need to use the fully qualified type name. Try: let ref:DatabaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.Database.database().reference()

Answer (score 0):

The release of Firebase 4.0 on May 17 has the changed the naming convention and can be found in this naming migration guide:

https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/ios/naming-migration-guide

Comment: How do you get a database reference in the new 4.0 version!?